# How do I deploy my site from github to heroku?

Tags: heroku, github

How do I deploy my site from github to heroku?

nbp-229-179:portfolio folder admin$ git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
nbp-229-179:portfolio folder admin$

Comment: It sounds like your your local git repository do not have a connection to the Heroku remote repository.  Do you see an alias for the heroku repository when you run the command `git remote -v`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [GitHub integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration), which will allow you to link your heroku app with github, not do any git pushes to heroku anymore but have your application automatically deployed.

With [pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines), you can automatically deploy a staging app with every push to the master branch, and manually promote the staging deployment to production.

Comment: Could you accept my answer then? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work